# How to pass json Address list to list Addres C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

Just I want to ask about my problem that I have table with html text input and user can add up to 10 row to enter customer Addresses and I'm using asp.net MVP pattern to design the app just want to ask how can I bass the json object to  properties method and extract the addresses form json and but them in to getter method

json

```
[{"name":"street_01","value":"bfb"},{"name":"city_01","value":"xcbcx"},{"name":"province_01","value":"xcbxcb"},{"name":"postalCode_01","value":"xcbcxb"},{"name":"street_02","value":"xcbcxb"},{"name":"city_02","value":"xcbcxb"},{"name":"province_02","value":"xcbbxc"},{"name":"postalCode_02","value":"cxbbxccxb"}]
```

IAddresView

```
 public  interface IAddressView
    {
        int AdressId { get; set; }
        int PersonId { get; set; }
        string Street { get; set; }
        string City  { get; set; }
        string Province { get; set; }
        char PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

personDetail.aspx.cs

```
    public partial class PersonDetails : System.Web.UI.Page , IPersonView
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public int PersonId
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return txtbFirstname.Text; }
            set { txtbFirstname.Text = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return txtbLastname.Text; }
            set { txtbFirstname.Text = value; }
        }

        public string MiddleName
        {
            get
            {
                return txtbMiddleName.Text; 
            }
            set { txtbMiddleName.Text = value; }
        }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return Convert.ToDateTime(txtbDateOfBirth.Text); }
            set { txtbDateOfBirth.Text = value.ToShortDateString(); }
        }

        public char Gender
        {
            get { return Convert.ToChar(ddlGender.SelectedValue); }
            set { ddlGender.SelectedValue = value.ToString(); }
        }

        public List<IAddressView> AddressesList
        {
            get
            {
                List<IAddressView> addresses = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IAddressView>(json);
                foreach (var item in addresses)
                {

                }                       
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        protected void btnAddPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PersonPresenter personPresenter = new PersonPresenter(this);

            if (personPresenter.AddPerson())
            {
                Response.Write("Add person");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("error");   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seing as the JSON is just a NameValueCollection, it is going to be difficult to deserialize it into anything without a lot of hand holding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the nuget manager console run `install-package newtonsoft.json`

```
var json = "[{\"name\":\"street_01\",\"value\":\"bfb\"},{\"name\":\"city_01\",\"value\":\"xcbcx\"},{\"name\":\"province_01\",\"value\":\"xcbxcb\"},{\"name\":\"postalCode_01\",\"value\":\"xcbcxb\"},{\"name\":\"street_02\",\"value\":\"xcbcxb\"},{\"name\":\"city_02\",\"value\":\"xcbcxb\"},{\"name\":\"province_02\",\"value\":\"xcbbxc\"},{\"name\":\"postalCode_02\",\"value\":\"cxbbxccxb\"}]";

var pd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonDetails>(json);
```

Good luck